# Communication between Chrome extension and running Windows service

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, windows-services

I am developing chrome extension which needs to communicate with my running service. I tried to use Chrome Native messaging, but I didn't manage to make the extension communicate with running service.
I did manage to communicate with native (not already running app), as described here:
[Google chrome native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for Native Messaging to "connect" to an already-running process.

Therefore, you have to either use something else (a local WebSockets server in your service is a good alternative idea) or make the Native Messaging host be some sort of "proxy": you can start a new one from Chrome, and it uses some other channel to communicate with the already-running service.